# Using the search maven rest api in my python program

Tags: python, api, maven

I am a beginner in python so this may be a quite simple question. I want to search the maven repository in my python program. I want to use the rest API on this page. https://search.maven.org/classic/#api

I want the code to execute json data and place into a txt file that my python code can later parse through. I just don't know how to call an api in the format it is given on the website. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I've been searching like crazy for any reference to an API to query the Maven Central repo. Your question gave me the answer :)

Comment: Could you use the API to get data in structured (e.g. json) format? @Mig82

Answer (score 1):

I found this api to search for maven dependencies with group id and artifact id. It gives response in json format.

```
https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:group_id a:artifact_id
```

**Note:**
There is a space between g:group_id and a:artifact_id

**Example:**

Request: `https://search.maven.org/solrsearch/select?q=g:org.apache.logging.log4j%20a:log4j-to-slf4j`

Response:

```
{
   "responseHeader":{
      "status":0,
      "QTime":0,
      "params":{
         "q":"g:org.apache.logging.log4j a:log4j-to-slf4j",
         "core":"",
         "indent":"off",
         "spellcheck":"true",
         "fl":"id,g,a,latestVersion,p,ec,repositoryId,text,timestamp,versionCount",
         "start":"",
         "sort":"score desc,timestamp desc,g asc,a asc",
         "spellcheck.count":"5",
         "rows":"",
         "wt":"json",
         "version":"2.2"
      }
   },
   "response":{
      "numFound":1,
      "start":0,
      "docs":[
         {
            "id":"org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j",
            "g":"org.apache.logging.log4j",
            "a":"log4j-to-slf4j",
            "latestVersion":"2.14.1",
            "repositoryId":"central",
            "p":"jar",
            "timestamp":1615094009000,
            "versionCount":37,
            "text":[
               "org.apache.logging.log4j",
               "log4j-to-slf4j",
               "-sources.jar",
               "-javadoc.jar",
               "-test-sources.jar",
               ".jar",
               ".pom"
            ],
            "ec":[
               "-sources.jar",
               "-javadoc.jar",
               "-test-sources.jar",
               ".jar",
               ".pom"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "spellcheck":{
      "suggestions":[
         
      ]
   }
}
```